# PHP if variables are not empty, echo

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm working with this [XML file](http://www.gostanford.com/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml) that has some empty attributes, in which case I want to skip that entire attribute's list item. Unfortunately my code still shows everything, even if one of the attributes are empty. I'm sure there's a simpler (and working) way to do this. Here's my [page](http://bit.ly/j2n0m4) and code:

```
$file = 'http://www.gostanford.com/*****/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach($xml as $event_date){
    if(isset($event_date->event['vn']) && isset($event_date->event['hn']) && isset($event_date->event['vs']) && isset($event_date->event['hs']))
    { 
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<h3>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' vs ', $event_date->event['hn'], '</h3>';
        echo '<p><strong>', $event_date->event['local_time'], '</strong></p>';
        echo '<h3>', $event_date->event['vs'], ' - ', $event_date->event['hs'], '</h3>';
        echo '</li>';   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `isset` with `!empty`

Comment: I discovered one problem with this. If either team was shutout, i.e. scored a "0", the entire score is excluded. How can this be edited to include zeros? *isset* won't work, as it includes empty results, which I definitely want to avoid.

Comment: @Ryan: well, you need to use compose condition with `isset` and `strlen` as @mario proposed :-S

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that and don't see @mario's response. Do you know how I can do this? Thank you :)

Comment: @Ryan: `isset($var) && strlen($var)`